# cypress does not navigate to next page on button click in Angular

Tags: cypress

I am trying to test web application build in Angular with Cypress.
On clicking a button it should navigate to the next page. However this is not working in Cypress. The application is working fine. Below is the html page.

Comment: Can you add the HTML to the question please?

Comment: Yes please show the HTML and the Cypress test. It probably is not cypress..

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h2>Login</h2>
<div class="div1">
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif" />
        <a [routerLink]="['/register']" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Added html code